# Sort measure by value Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I would like to order the following measure for the value marked in the attachment...

But I don't know how

measure:
RowNum =
CALCULATE (
COUNT ( vista_logistica_per_mappa_allocazioni[Indice] ),
FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( vista_logistica_per_mappa_allocazioni ), vista_logistica_per_mappa_allocazioni[Indice] <= MAX ( vista_logistica_per_mappa_allocazioni[Indice] ) )
)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8g73.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your table using that measure:

Click on the three dots above the table, then sort by --> RowNum. You can then choose whether to sort in descending or ascending order